# How does AngularJS recognize a function as controller directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am looking at [Angular API reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angController). It says that ngController is a directive, and give the following example:

```
function SettingsController($scope) {
 $scope.name = "John Smith";
}
```

This looks exactly like a plain Javascript function, with argument $scope passed in. I thought to define directives, we need to call:

```
app.directive("name", func())
```

Does Angular treats any function with $scope argument as controller directive? Or only if we modify DOM element to include ng-controller = "SettingsController" that SettingsController will be interpreted as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngController` is the directive (directives are always referred to in the DOM--Angular allows you to specify directives via tag names, attributes, class names and comments). The `ngController` directive is written so that it will create a controller instance based on the name that is passed in to the directive (in this case the string `"SettingsController"`. The function itself is not a directive.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my misconception. Now, if I can pass any function to the directive, what would be the difference between a plain JS function as above, and `myApp.controller("SettingsController", function() {})`?

Comment: No problem! And no difference. The `ngController` directive is smart enough to find the function on the global scope, but I personally *hate* this pattern and *always* recommend people use `myApp.controller` to define controller functions.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the recommendation.